# Android activity theme goes behind navigation and status bar

Tags: android, splash-screen

In order to create a simple splash theme, I created a layer-list as following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:opacity="opaque">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorAccent"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@mipmap/test_mipmap"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:scaleType="center"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And created a style using that:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
    </style>
```

Then used this style as Application theme in AndroidManifest

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"> ... </application>
```

When I ran the application, I noticed that the splash screen is somewhat full screen and status bar and navigation bar are being displayed in front of it. But once the main layout is loaded, it is displayed between navigation and status bars.

Here is the screenshot:

[image: splash screen]

Above, it is clearly shown that the blue circle is behind the status bar!

If I create activity layout as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/background_splash"> ... </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and put the same drawable as the background of the layout, the circle is displayed at the right place! (From my point of view)

[image]

What I want is to make splash theme's size be the same as layout. Almost forgot to mention that I'm working with minSdkVersion version 16

Comment: why are you setting application level theme to SplashTheme? I think its wrong. Use Splash style for only Splash Activity , splash screen should not have toolbar , right?

Comment: Your SplashTheme go in the Activity tag, not in Application tag if you do that you override all activities themes in your app. So only use SplashTheme in the <activity  android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"></activity>of the manifest

Comment: I do aware of what you guys have mentioned. But here there is only one activity in this example and its only a demo app to reproduce the issue.